# Can I automate that the React app build to be deployed on GoDaddy server from GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, create-react-app, godaddy-api

Usually, I use Netlify to deploy my React app which auto-publishes the code for every GitHub push.

Can I do something similar with shared hosting like GoDaddy server, because for every change I have to make a build and then have to manually upload all the build files to the server by using file manager.

Is there any possibility to automate this process?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it; you can use the GitHub actions to deploy using something like rsync or something like https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

Read the following tutorial, which I think will help you.

https://dev.to/madalitsonyemba/continuous-deployment-on-shared-hosting-with-github-actions-5agi